# Cloud Firestore: query for an item's availability given a timestamp

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-modeling

Imagine an Airbnb like app. A `rentals` collection contains documents with fields `start` and `end` of type timestamp that records the start date and end date of the rental (year, month and day only). Inside my Flutter app, when a user wants to make a new rental request, I need to check if the request interferes with any existing rentals. Would it be too much to store an array of `Timestamp` objects that contain the amount of days, then use `arrayContains` to query/check?

For example:

```
rental #1
    start: Jan 1
    end: Jan 2
    days: [Jan 1, Jan 2]
rental #2
    start: Jan 6
    end: Jan 10
    days: [Jan 6, Jan 7, Jan 8, Jan 9, Jan 10]
```

Suppose the user wants to book a rental for Jan 3-4. I would run a loop and query for documents with `arrayContains: Jan 3` and `arrayContains: Jan 4` and if it returns any documents, then I know the rental request date is invalid. The maximum amount of days a user can rent is 27 days, although I expect the average rental duration to last under 7 days. Is my method viable? I could change the maximum rental duration from 27 to 14 possibly.

The other method I came up with is to query for the rentals immediately before and after the desired pickup time. So using the above example, if my desired rental date is Jan 3-4, I would query for the closest rental that ends before Jan 3 and the closest rental that starts after Jan 4. However, the issue I'm running into is what if the user in rental #1 decides to extend their rental from Jan 1-2 to Jan 1-3 (before our user is able to refresh their app)? Or if a particular listing has no rental history associated with it.

Comment: This sounds like you just need to see if the rental start date is between start and end and if not, check to see if the rental end date is between start and end, right? So two queries and you would know if there are any conflicts. You didn't indicate your code base but here's the Swift docs [For example, you can combine the queryStartingAtValue and queryEndingAtValue methods to limit the results to a specified range of values](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#filtering_data)